# Exception - The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, exception, model-view-controller

I started logging exceptions within my application and I am receiving the exception multiple times a day:

```
The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.
```

My site is using HTTPS, with the following in FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        #if (!DEBUG)
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); 
        #endif
    }
}
```

Is there any way to find out the origin of the resource that is trying to be accessed so that it can be prevented? Also, how to recreate in my local environment because it only seems to happen in production. I tried navigating to a url without the HTTPS but this does not cause the exception.

Comment: Have you built locally in the Release build configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to look at your IIS logs (or whatever server you use to host your site). You will see all requests there.

Note that you can't prevent external callers to try HTTP - i.e. many automatic vulnerability scanners start with HTTP and may flood your logs with random php/jsp requests.

For dev environment - if you look at the code attribute added only for non-debug build - commenting that `#if (!DEBUG)` will likely reproduce the problem locally. Note that you probably will need to actually setup SSL on your dev environment to try end-to-end scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing production logs i have seen this in the past as well.  Research into the remote host IP and UserAgent lead us to believe it was a web crawler.